# Can i get the exact results as like google by passing just keyword?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-search-api

I want to search places by keyword match.

I have used Google Map Places API for this and passed the following arguments for search in this name is dynamically added from search textbox.

```
  var search = {
          bounds: map.getBounds(),
          keyword:[name] //name=dentist

        };
```

I am getting results in this but these results are not same as I got from google search.

Suppose if I enter dentist and choose location Ahmadabad in auto complete then I need the search results exactly as I search "dentist in ahmedabad" in google.

Is it possible to get same results as google?
Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places):

> The functions in the Google Places JavaScript library enable your application to search for places (defined in this API as establishments, geographic locations, or prominent points of interest) contained within a defined area, such as the bounds of a map, or around a fixed point.

In your case use **`Text Search Requests`**:

> The Google Places Text Search service is a web service that returns information about a set of places based on a string — for example "**pizza in New York**" or "**shoe stores near Ottawa**". The service responds with a list of places matching the text string and any location bias that has been set. The search response will include a list of places. You can send a Place Details request for more information about any of the places in the response.

Text Searches are initiated with a call to the **`PlacesService`**'s **`textSearch()`** method.

```
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.textSearch(request, callback);
```

You must also pass a callback method to **`textSearch()`**, to handle the results object and a **`google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus`** response.

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    query: 'restaurant'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have used nearby search for finding the keyword from location (Get from auto complete) but not getting exact same results as google finding.

I will try to text search as you suggested.